# Remove blank element from array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

When I'm saving multiple select from a ruby on rails form it appears to be adding a blank element at the front. How do I remove it? The field is selected_player.

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"H8W7qPBezubyeU0adnTGZ4oJqYErin1QNz5oK0QV6WY=",
 "schedule"=>{"event"=>"1",
 "result_id"=>"",
 "time"=>"26/10/2012",
 "duration"=>"15",
 "arrival_time"=>"14",
 "location_id"=>"25",
 "selected_players"=>["", "38", "41"],
 "team_id"=>"1",
 "opponent_id"=>"7",
 "home_or_away"=>"Home"},
 "commit"=>"Save Event"}
```

controller

```
def update
  @schedule = Schedule.find(params[:id])
  @user = User.find(current_user)
  @players = User.where(:team_id => current_user[:team_id]).all

  respond_to do |format|
    if @schedule.update_attributes(params[:schedule])
      Notifier.event_added(@user,@schedule).deliver
      format.html { redirect_to(@schedule,
                                :notice => "#{event_display_c(@schedule.event)} vs #{@schedule.opponent.name} was successfully updated.") }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    else
      format.html { render :action => "edit" }
      format.json { render :json => @schedule.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ref [`reject!`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-reject) of Array class

```
params["schedule"]["selected_players"] = ["", "38", "41"]
params["schedule"]["selected_players"].reject!{|a| a==""} #gives params["selected_players"] = ["38", "41"]
```

Comment: thats given me `undefined method `reject!' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: Please check my edited answer change `params["selected_players"]` to `params["schedule"]["selected_players"]`

Comment: to avoid issues where the params may be incomplete you could add a try : ```params["schedule"]["selected_players"].try(:delete_if, &:blank?)```

Answer (score 20):

This works for empty strings:

```
array.delete_if(&:empty?)
```

To filter out empty strings and nil values use:

```
array.delete_if(&:blank?)
```

Example:

```
>> a = ["A", "B", "", nil]
=> ["A", "B", "", nil]
>> a.delete_if(&:blank?)
=> ["A", "B"]
```

Comment: This works perfectly and can easily be added to the model logic in a before save function.

Answer (score 2):

This should work as well.

```
params["schedule"]["selected_players"].reject!(&:blank?)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
params["selected_players"].select!{|val| !val.empty?}
```

should work

Answer (score 0):

What is "selected_players"? Is it something like "collection_singular_ids" of the collection associations? If so, you can leave it as it is, because ActiveRecord will remove the blank elements from the array with following code:

```
ids = Array.wrap(ids).reject { |id| id.blank? }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle this in the **model** rather than the **controller** you can add a setter method like this

```
def selected_players=(param_array)
  write_attribute(:selected_players, param_array.reject(&:blank?))
end
```

Answer (score -3):

I think `params["selected_players"].compact` is the most succinct.

Docs are here: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-compact

Comment: This will not work for empty strings like the OP wants.